# Non stop GET request in Wordpress Access Log

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running an e-commerce store on top of Wordpress/Woo-commerce and I'm wondering whether it's normal to have an almost non-stop GET request log in apache's access log.

My website is hosted on Amazon EC2 running on Wordpress Bitnami's image.

Here's part of the log:

`172.31.33.229 - - [09/May/2020:14:18:10 +0000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1589033890.9472939968109130859375 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.31.33.229 - - [09/May/2020:14:18:10 +0000] "GET /product-category/printable-templates/wedding-templates/wedding-invitation-templates?query_type_color=or&filter_color=bluebrowncoralgreenturquoise&product_orderby=rating HTTP/1.1" 301 -
172.31.33.229 - - [09/May/2020:14:18:11 +0000] "GET /product-category/printable-templates/wedding-templates/wedding-invitation-templates/?query_type_color=or&filter_color=bluebrowncoralgreenturquoise&product_orderby=rating HTTP/1.1" 200 17499
172.31.33.229 - - [09/May/2020:14:18:15 +0000] "GET /product-category/printable-templates/wedding-templates/wedding-invitation-templates?query_type_color=or&filter_color=purpleredturquoise&product_view=list&product_count=45 HTTP/1.1" 301 -
172.31.33.229 - - [09/May/2020:14:18:16 +0000] "GET /product-category/printable-templates/wedding-templates/wedding-invitation-templates/?query_type_color=or&filter_color=purpleredturquoise&product_view=list&product_count=45 HTTP/1.1" 200 17390
172.31.33.229 - - [09/May/2020:14:18:21 +0000] "GET /product-category/printable-templates/wedding-templates?query_type_color=or&filter_color=black%2Cblue%2Ccoral%2Cmagenta%2Corange%2Cpeach%2Cturquoise HTTP/1.1" 301 -
172.31.33.229 - - [09/May/2020:14:18:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 230`

What's weird is that eventually, it logs 100% CPU usage causing my server to go frozen. If I restart the EC2 instance, everything will be back to normal again until after around more than 12hours on the average.

Note that 172.x.x.x is part of my subnet, I don't understand why I have this log.

Another clue would be in the top, what's eating my CPU is numerous entries of
php-fpm: pool wordpress.

The URL is https://templatesandvectors.com.

Comment: I'm using https. I'll add the URL above.

Comment: Btw. I updated the log to add the cron job. I'm not sure if it's relevant to the problem.